# Modal increase width using vw

Tags: css, sass, less

Increase modal size probably around width: 70vw and add a minimum width in pixels.

In order for the text in the field not to be clipp or cut I wanted to widen the modal probably around width: 70vw and add a minimum width in pixels. Anyone has an idea of that regarding css ?

[image]

## math dialog or modal container

```
.mat-dialog-container {
    display: block;
    padding: 24px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: inherit;
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

## mat dialog

```
<mat-dialog-container aria-modal="true" class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c38-16 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogContainer ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" id="mat-dialog-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mat-dialog-title-1" style="transform: none;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the css property

```
min-width:100px;
max-width:70vw;
```

Comment: How do you extend the modal width ?

Comment: Change the width property.

Comment: it is still the same

Comment: Use the max-width property then.

Comment: still the same Sir , the width of the modal does not change

Comment: the modal changes width when i try to put vm to min-width

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEPWGCY8MICD change text in this in the modal to see the increase or decrease in the modal width

Comment: I want a fix modal width around 70vm add a minimum width in pixels.